# How can I make one list from multiple individual lists that is in one variable with case i=n?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have data like this:

```
In[1]: print(z)
Out[2]:
ID          False
CITY        True
ID_STATE    False
STATE       False
ID_COUNTRY  False
COUNTRY     False
AGE         False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
ID          False
CITY        False
ID_STATE    False
STATE       False
ID_COUNTRY  False
COUNTRY     False
AGE         False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
ID          False
CITY        False
ID_STATE    False
STATE       False
ID_COUNTRY  False
COUNTRY     False
AGE         False
Name: 2, dtype: bool
ID          False
CITY        False
ID_STATE    False
STATE       False
ID_COUNTRY  False
COUNTRY     False
AGE         False
Name: 3, dtype: bool
```

Then I pass this to lists but I don't know if is necessary or it could be converted to just one list at once:

```
In[3]: print(z.tolist())
out[4]:
[False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
...
```

Then I would like to get a list from all the bool list data such as:

```
lst=[False, True, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

I would appreciate if anyone have an idea. Thanks.

Comment: Your first output doesn't make sense. Is it supposed to be a lilst of lists? But there's no `[]` for the outer list.

Comment: It looks like you just want to flatten the list of lists. The fact that they're booleans is irrelevant.

Comment: No. It supposed to be many list that I wanto to make into one @Barmar . Thank you for answering.

Comment: But how does `print(z)` print many lists?

Comment: @Barmar Because I have bool data that I convert to list: `z=rows.tolist()` .

Comment: That should produce a list of lists, not lots of separate lists.

Comment: If you're using numpy, you can use `rows.flatten().tolist()`

Comment: I have edited the code @Barmar. I hope have been more specific. Any idea?

Comment: See the pandas `ravel()` method to flatten a series.

Comment: I have tried and did not get the expected output. @Barmar

Comment: `z.ravel().flatten().tolist()`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but I did not get it in one list. It just appear as individual lists. @Barmar

Comment: You need to show us what you tried; there's no `ravel` or `flatten` anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can  add them together using `+`.

```
res = list()
for i in z:
    res += i
```